# How to interpret the results of the calibration (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration, calibration

I performed the calibration with chessboard (I defined the size of the corner in mm). Now, are the results of the calibration (matrix roto translation) in mm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and long answer: yes.

You basically set the units when you define the chessboard square size, so since you defined it in mm, your results will be in mm.

**Edit:** Keep in mind though that the reprojection error is in pixels and not in mm.